# Number storing in exponential foramt in varchar column

Tags: sql-server

[image]

Original number is 10190513 and it is getting stored as 1.01905e+007

also not giving correct result when  I am trying to convert like below.

SELECT CONVERT(numeric(16,0), CAST(result AS FLOAT))

How to fix this problem?

it is giving output as 10190500 instead of 10190513

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is working as expected when it converts 1.01905e+007 to 10190500. The final two digits are being lost upstream, and since they don't exist in your data SQL Server has no way to restore them.

What process/code is putting the "result" value into that column? That's where your issue is, but it's impossible to give a fix with the info you've given.